# Img src value not changing on change dynamic content

Tags: jquery

Check the code bellow. I am trying to display picture in real time when a image file is chossen. I already did it like bellow which seems to be working just stuck in line `$(".hpicFile").closest(".catHpic").attr('src', e.target.result);`. I wanted change ` attr value and it seems i am not doing right here so its not changing the attr value. Whats wrong i am doing here?

Html:

```
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="row" id="hbar">
       
        
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card-footer" style="text-align:right;">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="btn-Newbar">New Bar</button>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
//add bar
$("#btn-Newbar").on("click", function () {
    $("#hbar").append("<div class='col-4' style='margin-bottom:20px;'><div class='row'><div class='col-3'><img src='' class='catHpic' style='height:80px;width:80px;'></div><div class='col-9'><input type='file' class='hpicFile'><div class='input-group mb-3' style='margin-top:10px;'><div class='input-group-prepend'><span class='input-group-text url'>URL</span></div><input type='text' class='form-control' aria-describedby='basic-addon1'></div></div></div></div>");
});
//display highlight pic real time 
$(document).on("change", ".hpicFile", function (e) {
    //console.log(e);
    //console.log(this.closest);
    if (e.target.files[0] != null) {
        //console.log(e.target.files[0]);
        $.each(this.files, function (key, file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                //display images real time
                console.log(e.target.result);
                $(".hpicFile").closest(".catHpic").attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [.parent()](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) function with [prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) to target the img of dynamically added input `type="file"`

Also, to target the right `parent` and `prev` you need to assign your `$(this)` in your `change` function as `var findImg = $(this)` and use that in your `reader.onload` function. If you use straight `$(this)` then `.onload` function does not where to find and look for to change the `src`.

You can add multiple `new bar` via `append` and your `img` will be loaded in *real time* in that specific choose `file` img `src`.

**Live Demo:**

```js
//add bar
$("#btn-Newbar").on("click", function() {
  $("#hbar").append("<div class='col-4' style='margin-bottom:20px;'><div class='row'><div class='col-3'><img src='' class='catHpic' style='height:80px;width:80px;'></div><div class='col-9'><input type='file' class='hpicFile'><div class='input-group mb-3' style='margin-top:10px;'><div class='input-group-prepend'><span class='input-group-text url'>URL</span></div><input type='text' class='form-control' aria-describedby='basic-addon1'></div></div></div></div>");
});

//display highlight pic real time 
$(document).on("change", ".hpicFile", function(e) {
  var imgSrc = $(this).parent('div').prev().find('.catHpic') //find img
  if (e.target.files[0] != null) {
    //console.log(e.target.files[0]);
    $.each(this.files, function(key, file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        //display images real time
        imgSrc.attr('src', e.target.result);
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-body">
    <div class="row" id="hbar">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card-footer" style="text-align:right;">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" id="btn-Newbar">New Bar</button>
</div>
```